What is the thermal radius of the universe's "horizon"?
I have repeatedly come across the statement that every time there's a horizon (could be an event horizon of a black hole, or a Rindler horizon associated with acceleration), the vacuum state differs for varying observers, leading to the observation of thermal radiation.
How does the manifest when it comes to the horizon of the universe? (the horizon between us and parts of the universe that are causally cut off because of the accelerating expansion of the universe)

From my understanding, its the apparent horizon...
